# Calling an inner parse method from the main parse method in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapper which goes to a website and crawls some articles, what i want to do is to extract a link from each article and make a request to that link to get some more details about that article. The article details are stored in it's own individual link so it is necessary to make request. My problem is, that I cannot make request from the main parse method to the secondary parse method. My secondary parse method is: parse_article_page

Upon debugging, it comes to the nested yield, where i am trying to yield the method "parse_article_page" but doesnot enter the method. The url that i'm constructing for which i want to make this request are also correct (the urls are strings). I have opened the individual job pages in browser and in scrapy shell and both of them seem to work. Help will be appreciated.

```
import scrapy
import os
import json
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import traceback

class MyScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "job_scraper"
    DOMAIN = 'totaljobs.com'

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 10,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 16,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 16,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 5,
        'OFFSITE_ENABLED': False
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = "https://www.totaljobs.com/jobs/it/in-reading?page={}"
        for page_number in range(1, 152):
            url = base_url.format(page_number)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_article_listing, meta={'delay': 10}, dont_filter=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_domain(response, remove_http=True):
        uri = urlparse(response.url)
        if remove_http:
            domain = f"{uri.netloc}"
        else:
            domain = f"{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}"
        return domain

    def parse_article_listing(self, response):
        job_articles = response.xpath('//article[starts-with(@id, "job-item-")]')

        for article in job_articles:
            job_data = {}
            # Your parsing logic here
            yield job_data  # Yield the job data dictionary for each job

            try:
                extracted_url = article.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "res-r3jqsu")]/@href').get()
                if extracted_url:
                    job_url = 'https://www.' + self.DOMAIN + extracted_url
                    yield scrapy.Request(
                        job_url,
                        headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"},
                        callback=self.parse_article_page,
                        dont_filter=True
                    )
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()

    def parse_article_page(self, response):
        print("Processing job page:", response.url)
        # logic for parsing job pages here
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue is caused by the http server.  When you send a request for any of the secondary urls, it seems to just stall forever until it reaches the scrapy timeout of 180 seconds.  But the secondary pages that you are attempting to crawl don't appear to be parseable by scrapy anyway